# Is it possible to restore PostgreSQL data without overwriting existing data?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have 2 backup files and I want to merge all this data on my database.

I try to use pg_restore but when I use with the second database file I lost the first data set.

Look for my command:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -c --if-exists -d ravpacheco_db "C:\Users\ravpacheco\xpto1.backup"
```

I also search [all options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html) flags for pg_restore command but I can't find some usefull thing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Answer (score -1):

My problem is with my pg_dump command. If I created a backup file only with data my restore will work

Now I'm using this pg_dump command

```
pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=<table> <database>
```

I resolved my problem using this stackoverflow thread

Comment: Hello @raphael, of course I'm referring to this thread. If you know that to use pg_restore you need before use pg_dump you will understand! ;)